# how do I count how many time the page is loaded in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I would like to count how many times a page is loaded.
I think useEffect() needs to be used but I have no idea what would be the dependency for page load.

For example, once you hit 'refresh' on your browser, the count should be increased by 1.
And it doesn't fall into an infinite loop.

Thank you in Advanced.

Comment: You can use session storage for that with respect to window location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the console.count() method in the body of the page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/count